# Shortcut for matching accented characters

Tags: regex, pcre

In regex, there are shortcuts, like `\w` or `a-z`.

In the same way, is there an alternative to writing all wanted accented symbols (for instance, transforming `[éèàêâûôîùÈ...]` into `\ê`)?

Comment: Which language/flavor?

Comment: pcre (I added it in the tags for more convenience)

Comment: I think this is tricky because there's no universal definition of an "accentuated symbol" [sic].

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
$t = "Normal text éèàêâûôîùÈ more text";

preg_match_all('/[^\P{Latin}\x00-\x80]+/u', $t, $m);
print_r($m);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => éèàêâûôîùÈ
        )

)
```

Basically, this selects all "latin" characters (=letters), except those in the lower ascii range (=a..z). Not sure if this can be called a "shortcut" though ;)

Comment: Of course, that entirely ignores non-latin text with diacriticals.